# Python gives me error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied but the file I am trying to access has open permissions

Tags: python, errno

I have encountered the same issue a couple of times when trying to read Python files that are stored under 'C:\Users\kubjasp\' and in the past I have just moved the files to another location, but that really isn't a true fix and, in this case, I cannot do that so without modifying a LOT of package locations.

The file I am trying to access has read permissions for all users and so do all the parent folders.

Checklist so far:

- File permissions are correct
- I do not have the file explorer open at this location
- I do not have any other programs using the file

Why would I possibly be getting this error in this case?  Should I simply not have anything installed in here?

There surely must be some glaring mistake I am making here to be getting this error in such a situation.

Thanks!

EDIT

The reason I did not include the code is because my error message is occurring when trying to run a module that has files stored under the User directory described above. Python is locating the module files then telling me that it has no permission to read them.

Miraculously, though, it worked today without me making any changes at all. Seems that resetting my computer has fixed it. Perhaps its possible that some background process was using the files?

Comment: It's impossible for us to really get to the bottom of the error you're experiencing, without you giving us a way for us to replicate the error itself (IE, give us a minimal example of your code). However, there could be a simple thing such as instead of trying to open a file, you're actually just targeting the folder `'C:\Users\kubjasp\'` instead of say a file under it called `'C:\Users\kubjasp\test.txt'`. That would result in the same error. This piece of code should replicate your error if that is the case: `open('C:\Users\kubjasp\', 'r')`

Comment: In addition to @HampusLarsson 's comment, I believe Windows may deny access to a file that's being used by another process (e.g. an Excel file currently open on MS Office).

Comment: Did you try writing to another file? is it in the same dir? 
also try using os.path (a backslash might not be what you think it is)